# C# Reading and Summarizing Text File with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, text

I've read MANY different solutions for the separate functions of LINQ that, when put together would solve my issue. My problem is that I'm still trying to wrap my head about how to put LINQ statements together correctly. I can't seem to get the syntax right, or it comes up mish-mash of info and not quite what I want.

I apologize ahead of time if half of this seems like a duplicate. My question is more specific than just reading the file. I'd like it all to be in the same query.

To the point though..

I am reading in a text file with semi-colon separated columns of data.

An example would be:

```
US;Fort Worth;TX;Tarrant;76101
US;Fort Worth;TX;Tarrant;76103
US;Fort Worth;TX;Tarrant;76105
US;Burleson;TX;Tarrant;76097
US;Newark;TX;Tarrant;76071
US;Fort Worth;TX;Tarrant;76103
US;Fort Worth;TX;Tarrant;76105
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
var items = (from c in (from line in File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
    let columns = line.Split(';')
    where columns[0] == "US"
    select new
    {
        City = columns[1].Trim(),
        State = columns[2].Trim(),
        County = columns[3].Trim(),
        ZipCode = columns[4].Trim()
    })
    select c);
```

That works fine for reading the file. But my issue after that is I don't want the raw data. I want a summary.

Specifically I need the count of the number of occurrences of the City,State combination, and the count of how many times the ZIP code appears.

I'm eventually going to make a tree view out of it. 
My goal is to have it laid out somewhat like this:

```
- Fort Worth,TX (5)
       -  76101 (1)
       -  76103 (2)
       -  76105 (2)  

- Burleson,TX (1)
       - 76097 (1)

- Newark,TX (1)
     - 76071 (1)
```

I can do the tree thing late because there is other processing to do.

**So my question is:** How do I combine the counting of the specific values in the query  itself? I know of the GroupBy functions and I've seen Aggregates, but I can't get them to work correctly. How do I go about wrapping all of these functions into one query?

**EDIT**: I think I asked my question the wrong way. I don't mean that I HAVE to do it all in one query... I'm asking **IS THERE** a clear, concise, and efficient way to do this with LINQ in one query? If not I'll just go back to looping through.

If I can be pointed in the right direction it would be a huge help.
If someone has an easier idea in mind to do all this, please let me know.

I just wanted to avoid iterating through a huge array of values and using Regex.Split on every line.

Let me know if I need to clarify.

Thanks!

*EDIT 6/15***

I figured it out. Thanks to those who answered it helped out, but was not quite what I needed. As a side note I ended up changing it all up anyways. LINQ was actually slower than doing it other ways that I won't go into as it's not relevent. As to those who made multiple comments on "It's silly to have it in one query", that's the decision of the designer. All "Best Practices" don't work in all places. They are guidelines. Believe me, I do want to keep my code clear and understandable but I also had a very specific reasoning for doing it the way I did.

I do appreciate the help and direction.

Below is the prototype that I used but later abandoned.

```
    /* Inner LINQ query Reads the Text File and gets all the Locations.
     * The outer query summarizes this by getting the sum of the Zips 
     * and orders by City/State then ZIP */


var items = from Location in(
    //Inner Query Start
    (from line in File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
    let columns = line.Split(';')
    where columns[0] == "US" & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(columns[4])
    select new
    {
    City = (FM.DecodeSLIC(columns[1].Trim()) + " " + columns[2].Trim()),
    County = columns[3].Trim(),
                   ZipCode = columns[4].Trim()
    }
    ))
    //Inner Query End
    orderby Location.City, Location.ZipCode  
                   group Location by new { Location.City, Location.ZipCode , Location.County} into grp
            select new
            {
            City = grp.Key.City,
            County = grp.Key.County,
            ZipCode = grp.Key.ZipCode,
            ZipCount = grp.Count()      
            };
```

Comment: I have, My problem is I don't know how to get it to work right. I've tried following the tutorials, copy and pasted others code and tried to modify it... Seeing if someone can help with the syntax. I'll edit to make that clear.

Comment: `.GroupBy(addr => addr.City+","+addr.State)`

Comment: On what line? I just tried adding that in different ways all over the place and came up with nothing. Grouping by one of the criteria only helps me get the count for the City,State anyways, how do I do double group bys so I can count City, State AND Zip separately? I appreciate the help, but my issue is I'm pretty new at LINQ and everyone seems to have their own style.

Comment: *" I'd like it all to be in the same query."* - That is a silly "requirement" that makes no sense.  The code should flow naturally from the problem being solved.  If it is clearer and still efficient to write it in multiple lines/queries than that's how it should be written.  Trying to condense everything into a single LINQ query is a waste of time unless it is simple to do and makes the code easier to maintain/read.

Comment: And that's the whole point of my question Ed. Is there an easy way to do this? That's like saying "SQL Aggregate queries are silly, it just makes the query more confusing. I'll query it and then make the program add/count it/find the min/max".. If the functionality is built in that's great, and looking at LINQ I can almost bet it is. I just can't figure out HOW cause I'm not familiar enough with LINQ yet. Hence my question for a little guidance.

Comment: Regex is slow, and it complicates the code to iterate through everything and then add it to a dictionary/array/list or whatever. Then having to add it up again and put it in another container. When LINQ can do it for you all in one go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The downside of using File.ReadAllLines is that you have to pull the entire file into memory before operating over it. Also, using Columns[] is a bit clunky. You might want to consider my [article describing using DynamicObject and streaming](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-CSV-using-DynamicObject) the file as an alternative implemetnation. The grouping/counting operation is secondary to that discussion.

Comment: Very interesting read. It's a more involved version of what I eventually went for. The Columns[] was clunky and split is slower in my case that using Substring. Since all my files (different than in this example) were equally spaced values I just used Streamreader to iterate over it. Got it down from taking 3 seconds to .1 second with that method. Since I'll be using this class A LOT that made a huge difference. You are right on track though and I think I will use your method for another sub project! Lots of potential there.

Comment: Make sure to follow the additional posts to the original one as well as I modified the implementation in the follow-up posts. The DynamicObject and IEnumerator implementaiton are a bit involved, but the consuming code becomes quite concise.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var items = (from c in
                         (from line in File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
                          let columns = line.Split(';')
                          where columns[0] == "US"
                          select new
                                     {
                                         City = columns[1].Trim(),
                                         State = columns[2].Trim(),
                                         County = columns[3].Trim(),
                                         ZipCode = columns[4].Trim()
                                     })
                     select c);
        foreach (var i in items.GroupBy(an => an.City + "," + an.State))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})",i.Key, i.Count());
            foreach (var j in i.GroupBy(an => an.ZipCode))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" - {0} ({1})", j.Key, j.Count());

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no point getting everything into one query. It's better to split the queries so that it would be meaningful. Try this to your results

```
var grouped = items.GroupBy(a => new { a.City, a.State, a.ZipCode }).Select(a => new { City = a.Key.City, State = a.Key.State, ZipCode = a.Key.ZipCode, ZipCount = a.Count()}).ToList();
```

**Result screen shot**

[image]

**EDIT**

Here is the one big long query which gives the same output

```
var itemsGrouped = File.ReadAllLines(myFile).Select(a => a.Split(';')).Where(a => a[0] == "US").Select(a => new { City = a[1].Trim(), State = a[2].Trim(), County = a[3].Trim(), ZipCode = a[4].Trim() }).GroupBy(a => new { a.City, a.State, a.ZipCode }).Select(a => new { City = a.Key.City, State = a.Key.State, ZipCode = a.Key.ZipCode, ZipCount = a.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: love it, and it's elegant